# How to disable simultaneous build on drone io?

Tags: drone.io

I use drone as CI and want to know how I can disable simultaneous build. What's happening is that when I submit two commits to git repo, drone will trigger two build on each of the submit. How can I let the second build wait until the first one finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the [open source version](http://readme.drone.io) of Drone: set the `DOCKER_MAX_PROCS` environment variable of your drone agent to `1`, i.e. `docker run -e DOCKER_MAX_PROCS=1 [...] drone/drone:0.5 agent`. The agent will run one build concurrently, other builds will queue up.

See the [Installation Reference section](http://readme.drone.io/admin/installation-reference/) in the readme for more info.